# Where to execute initialization functions in Angular /w Electron?

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I am using Angular and Electron, and I have a `Preferences` object I would like to initialize (`Preferences.init()`) which needs to be executed before **any other code is executed**. Does Angular or Electron have a specific location where such initialization code should be executed?

At the moment I put it into the constructor of `AppComponent` but since the function is asynchronous, I have a race condition and occasionally the data is not properly initialized when needed. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where will this `Preferences` object be used?

Comment: Anyhow, this should be initialized before `BrowserWindow` is created.

Comment: Let me see your code snippet and I can help you with

Comment: Try the ```main.ts```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about putting it into `main.ts` and before `BrowserWindow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`APP_INITIALIZER`](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) dependency injection token to do a such thing:

Assuming you created a provider

```js
@Injectable()
export class ThingProvider {

    private thing: Thing = null;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    public getThing(): Thing {
        return this.thing;
    }

    load() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http
                .get('https://my-api.com/thing')
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(response => {
                    this.thing = response['value'];
                    resolve(true);
                })
        })
    }
}
```

Then, in your `app.module.ts` file:

```js
export function thingsProviderFactory(provider: ThingProvider) {
  return () => provider.load();
}
```

And finally, in the same file:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ThingProvider, 
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: thingsProviderFactory, deps: [ThingProvider], multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!